# Overflow Error on inserting data on Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  

            try {

                    Connections.con.Open();
                    string str = "INSERT INTO `Employee` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`, `ContactNumber`, `Username`, `Password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, Connections.con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtFirst.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtLast.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtAge.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtCon.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtUser.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtPass.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Registration Successful");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { 
                          MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
                    }
                    finally { 

                    Connections.con.Close();
                    this.Dispose();
                    this.Close();
                    f1.Show(); 
       }          
    }
```

This code should save the first name last name age contact number username and password the user will enter but the problem is the OVERFLOW exception error pops up whenever i click the button.. please help I've been searching everywhere just to solve this problem but i can't find an answer

Comment: Are all access fields of a type compatible with text values?

Comment: The First Name, Last Name, Username, Password are all in text type in access data base and the age and contact number are in number data type

Comment: how big is the number field in Access? Can you change this to text type in the db?

Comment: The contact number should be a string not a numeric field. What happen if you have a telephone number that is too big to be interpreted as an numeric (of type integer)

Comment: age and contact are in number data type and a long integer

Comment: Try to not insert the contact number. Do you still have the exception?

Comment: should i change the age and contacts data type in text instead of number? Steve

Comment: wait i'll try but whenever i keep a blank textbox there is an error data mismatch

Comment: No just try to remove the contact number from your query and from your parameters. Just to check if the problem is in this field or not

Comment: It worked!! changing the contact number and age to a string value not a numeric field! :D thanks!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AddWithValue method creates a parameter with a DataType equal to the value passed.
You pass strings so the parameter is created with a DataType string.
This will not work well when you try to insert that value in a numeric field.

Change your code to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtFirst.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtLast.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", Convert.ToInt32(txtCon.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtUser.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtPass.Text);
```

As a second guess, the contact number field is of type **numeric long**.
Access allow a number of this kind to be at maximum **2147483647**.

In this context it is perfectly possible that you have a telephone number that when is interpreted as a numeric value is bigger that this limit. As a consequence you get the overflow error.

I really suggest to use a string for a contact number with enough chars to accomodate for more than one telephone number (30 chars)

As a side note. I would also store the birth date and not the age otherwise next year you have a problem.

Comment: i used the code you revised and then changing the data type again to number and it show an error that the value is too long or too short

Comment: but when i changed the data type for age and contact number to a text data type it worked!....

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve this problem... and also thank you for giving me advice about the age changing it to a birth date